# Externalization of code- layout in ggplot

Tags: r, optimization, ggplot2, knitr

I would like to externalize my layouts in ggplot2 because my code gets very crowded.

Lets say I have a given layout which I apply on several plots in different functions. It looks like this:

```
    scale_fill_gradientn(guide="colourbar",colours=costum.colorbar_sand.blue.green)+
      theme (legend.title = element_text(size = 15,family="Arial"))+
      theme (legend.text = element_text(size = 12,family="Arial",angle=45))+
      theme (legend.position = "bottom")+
      coord_map(projection="mercator");
```

I would like to put it an external file or in an object and then call it into my plot function.

I tried read_chunk from the [knitr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html) like this: 
I saved the blank code as it is above in an R file and then tried to implement it in my function. Therefore i just wrote it down into the function like this

```
    function.xy(...){...some ggplot function...
    read_chunk("some\path")
    }
```

But it dind't work out.
I also tried `paste(read_chunk("some\path"))` but this dind't work eather.

Another idea I had was to save it as an object and the just paste the text but this wasn't quite working as well because i dind't figure out how to save it as a plain text object (if there is something like that). 
Can anyone advice me on how to do this?

Comment: If you are saving the theme changes in `file.R` then you access it by `source("path_to_file.R")`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Note: You don't have to keep retyping `theme()` for each option. You can just use commas to seperate additional settings within the original `theme(..., ..., ...)` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can externalize the layout code into a separate chunk. See [example 083](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/083-ggplot2-reference.Rmd) (and its [output](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/083-ggplot2-reference.md)) in the `knitr-examples` repository. The key is chunk references via `<<>>`.

Comment: You thought of everything didn't you!

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen haha, I just collect examples and solutions as users ask questions so that there is a central place to learn all the tricks.

Answer (score 5):

I do this one of two ways. In my file to be knit, I declare plot options that I know are going to be used frequently, saving grouped elements in a list, like so:

```
plot.option1 <- list(scale_fill_gradient(guide="colourbar",colours=costum.colorbar_sand.blue.green),
                     theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 15,family="Arial"),
                           legend.text = element_text(size = 12,family="Arial",angle=45),
                           legend.position = "bottom"),
                     coord_map(projection="mercator"))
```

Then it's just a matter of appending `+ plot.option1`

For example:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + plot.option1
```

If you have a lot of them (say for corporate themes) you can just as easily put them in a seperate script and then source it at the head of your file to be knit.

**Minimal example:**

```
plot.opt <- list(scale_color_brewer(palette="Blues"))
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, color=color)) + geom_point() + plot.opt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option quite similar to the one of @brandon-bertelsen is to create a custom function :

```
add.my.layout <- function(g) {
    g + scale_fill_gradientn(guide="colourbar",colours=costum.colorbar_sand.blue.green)+
      theme (legend.title = element_text(size = 15,family="Arial"))+
      theme (legend.text = element_text(size = 12,family="Arial",angle=45))+
      theme (legend.position = "bottom")+
      coord_map(projection="mercator")
}
```

And then in your code you can just do :

```
myggplot <- ggplot(...)
add.my.layout(myggplot)
```

You can define your functions in external R files if you wish.

Comment: Just a note, functions that don't have a specific return() value can be problematic. Personally, I would save to a variable and return(variable) for clarity.

Comment: Ah well, I read that there are speed benefits of not wrapping your result in return, that's why I tend to do it this way...